# SSDT: How to configure SchemaCompare Object settings in code

Tags: database-schema, sql-server-data-tools, dac, schema-compare

How to edit the SchemaCompare Settings in the SchemaComparison object?

$SchemaComparison = [SchemaComparison]::new( $SourceEndPoint, $TargetEndPoint )
$SchemaComparison.Options = $DeployOptions

I am particularly looking to Remove Database options, but the SchemaCompare settings do not appear to be accessible by code:

$SchemaComparison.Options.ExcludeDatabaseOptions #(not known property of the Options object)

$SchemaComparison.SettingsService #(not a known property)

How can I do in code what I can EASILY do from the SSDT compare UI?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  There is an excludedObjects property hiding in the options object.  It's an array of ObjectType enums:

```
$SchemaComparison.Options.ExcludeObjectTypes += [ObjectType]::Aggregates
$SchemaComparison.Options.ExcludeObjectTypes += [ObjectType]::ApplicationRoles
$SchemaComparison.Options.ExcludeObjectTypes += [ObjectType]::Assemblies
```

You can exclude any you want.  The MSDN includes the list here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.objecttype.aspx